# UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM -> PHP script

Tags: php, apache, utf-8, webserver

I have a PHP script, that works fine when I set the encoding of the file to UTF-8 without BOM or ANSI.

If I set the file to UTF-8 encoding, respectively with BOM, the output of the PHP file is messed up.

However now I encountered that when trying to install the same script on a russian operationg system (Win 7, XAAMP), that either Apache or PHP always delivers the output with BOM, thereby messing the output up.

Changing the encoding of the PHP file does not help in this case...

Is there any way to set APACHE or PHP to never use UTF-8 with BOM, no matter of the encoding of the PHP file?

Kind Regards!

Comment: Neither php nor apache add a BOM by magic AFAIK.

Comment: This was also my thaught - and this is true when you install XAAMP on an european based Windows 7 operating system, but for some reason I do not understand, when using an russion Win 7 operationg system, Apache or PHP is adding magically a BOM...

Answer (score 1):

The BOM is added when download the file... this is maybe a bug, but download a saveing the content in a file the BOM is not added... then the trick is download the file without BOM

```
  //Define filename
  $filename = 'FILE.TXT'; 

  //Remove BOM
  $txt= str_replace("\xEF\xBB\xBF", '', $file_txt);
  //Save File in Server
  file_put_contents($filename, $txt);

  //Start Download of the file
  ob_end_clean();
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
  header("Content-Length: ". filesize($filename).";"); 
  header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename);
  readfile($filename);
  die();
```

Comment: Saving content in file in /tmp and download it after helped me a lot because the online service swisspost doesn't accept anymore files with BOM and, while downloading directly csv/text file the browser add BOM by itself. You save me a precious time.